# Find serial number and redirect to appropriate url

Tags: php, html

I am creating a series of QR codes with serial numbers with a URL;
https://example.com/qr/qr.php?c=00000000000000001

I would like the various ranges of serial numbers to go to the appropriate page.

I had the idea to create a PHP page to handle the redirection, but I am struggling to get the numbers in the range.

Open to suggestions for alternative ways to do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Finding your code ... </title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// directs the user to page based on code

$code = $_GET['c'] ;
$page1 = 'https://example.com/dogs';
$page2 = 'https://example.com/cats';
$page3 = 'https://example.com/frogs';
$page4 = 'https://example.com/cows';



if( $code >= 1 || $code <= 10  or
    $code >= 100 || $code <= 150 )
 {
   //echo $page1 ; 
header('Location: .$page1') ;
    die() ;
}

if($code >= 11 || $code <= 20) {

 //      echo $page2 ; 
header('Location: .$page2') ;
    die() ;
}

if($code >= 21 || $code <= 30) {
    //        echo $page3 ; 
header('Location: .$page3') ;
    die() ;
}

if($code >= 31 || $code <= 40) {
    //    echo $page4 ; 
header('Location: .$page4') ;
    die() ;
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue comes from the way you wrote the if statement?

Make sure `$code` is of type integer:

```
var_dump($code);
if ( $code >= 1 && $code <= 10 || $code >= 100 && $code <= 150 ){
   // Do something when $code is between 1 and 10, or 100 and 150
}
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: Thank you .. that helped with the of returning the correct url.

Comment: Happy it's helping! Of course there is other ways to achieve this, but this is a good start. See this alternatively: https://www.taniarascia.com/the-simplest-php-router/

Comment: I don't think this answers the question completely. var_dump() is using here to find the type of the variable. To convert the variable to integer value, you have to use (int) typecasting. Could you please let me know why this answer is marked as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to convert the $code to integer or number format before checking it's value.

```
$code = (int) $code;
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is a great help to get the 0000 prefix number as a number

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted so that it helps others too